# How do I select a certain node in a tree in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, tree, adobe

I'm trying to get properties for one single node such as the name I've set for it or something. How can I go by just selecting this one node? I can do it with an event

```
e.currentTarget.selectedItem.@name;
```

But I need to grab it without the event, how can I go by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's better to get data from your data provider for xmlTree, because it's a XML/XMLList you can always use construction like

> myxml.nodename[0].@attribute

Comment: You are welcome. And you should set this question as answered, to not leave it here as opened.

Comment: Where can I do that? An actually I'm a little confused about the "items[0]" part, what would that be considered? A parent to the node?

Comment: if you move mouse on the answer there will be a big green "check" sign on the left. click it if you consider this answer is the best for your question.