# How could I grab a parent node in xml without an event?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, adobe

I need to grab a parent node in flex without an event listener. How could I go by doing this?

Example

```
myTree.parent.@attribute;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [parent()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#parent%28%29)

```
myTree.parent().@attribute;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to ask how I could grab it within a tree.

Comment: But you asked that same question 2 days ago?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796462/how-do-i-select-a-certain-node-in-a-tree-in-flex

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm trying to put this in better wording... I'll see about deleting double posts. I'm still not understanding this.

Comment: The other answer didn't explain things?  Then you should comment it and ask for further explanation, or perhaps even unaccept it (that's a bit harsh, though - I'd go with the comment first).

Comment: Perhaps this documentation page will help: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_8.html